# Как определить тип данных в ResultSet?

Tags: java

В программе получаю результаты запроса к базе данных в виде объекта `ResultSet`. Поля в базе данных разных типов, и заведомо я не знаю какой запрос будет выполнен и какой `ResultSet` будет передан в мою функцию.

Вне зависимости от типа данных в столбце базы данных, эту информацию можно получить как строку, или число, или как дату. Для этого используется методы `getString(int)`, `getInt(int)` и т.д.

Как узнать какой тип данных находится в этом столбце и в зависимости от этого использовать разные методы для получения данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для получения значения метод `getObject`, а затем определяйте тип (`getClass` или `instanceof`). Обратите внимание на документацию к методу.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем узнавать? Есть полиморфизм.